# How to link other JIRA dashboards to a central dashboard?

Tags: jira

I have several dashboards in JIRA and want to create a central one where there is a filter or gadget that will display links to the other dashboards. Is this possible?

Comment: I found a way to accomplish this. You can embed it in a issue ie the description field and use a filter to display that field of that issue

Answer (score 0):

You may save all of these dashboards' URLs and show them inside a gadget in your main dashboard.

Let's say one of your "other dashboard"s link is: your-jira-url.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=10000

Then, you can add a new gadget (like Text plugin which can show HTML) and add following HTML in that gadget:

```
<a href="your-jira-url.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=10000">Link to the other dashboard</a>
```

However, Text plugin is not enabled default because of the security issues. You may find the details on [Atlassian documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver073/gadgets-for-jira-applications-861257078.html).

Also, as an alternative, you may try [HTML for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1223462/html-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) plugin, or you may find some free alternatives from [Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?product=jira&query=HTML).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish this. You can embed it in a issue ie the description field and use a filter to display that field of that issue